# File upload/download asp.net c# security X-Content-Type-Options: no-sniff header, Content-Disposition header

Tags: c#, owasp

Our security team is able to upload a word document with a macro from one of the web page. The solution to block the files with macro is as below:

If uploaded files are downloaded by users, supply an accurate non-generic Content-Type header, the X-Content-Type-Options: no-sniff header, and also a Content-Disposition header that specifies that browsers should handle the file as an attachment.

How to implement the above fix on the web page with file upload and download feature ?